# Adding object to ArrayList sets objects values to null

Tags: java, android

I have a Retrofit request which requests a list of GroupAccount objects from my API. The API returns all values without a problem, so I then try to loop over the response in my activity, which retrieves the values perfectly, but once I call

```
//groupAccounts is my list, declared and initialised globally, groupAccount is the object I create at the end of each iteration
groupAccounts.add(groupAccount);
```

It sets all of the groupAccount objects values to null. Why is this happening?

Constructor in GroupAccount model class:

```
public GroupAccount(long groupAccountId,
                  long adminId,
                  String accountName,
                  String accountDescription,
                  int numberOfMembers,
                  BigDecimal totalAmountPaid,
                  BigDecimal totalAmountOwed,
                  int testResourceId) {

}
```

The request method with onResponse & onFailure:

```
public void getUserAssociatedAccounts(String userId){
Call<List<GroupAccount>> call = apiInterface.getUserAssociatedAccounts(userId);
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<GroupAccount>>() {
  @Override
  public void onResponse(Call<List<GroupAccount>> call, Response<List<GroupAccount>> response) {
    if(!response.isSuccessful()) {
      //Handle
    } else {
      if(response.body().size() > 0){
        for(int i=0; i<response.body().size(); i++) {

          //This is just for clarity
          long groupAccountId = response.body().get(i).getGroupAccountId();
          long adminId = response.body().get(i).getAdminId();
          String accountName = response.body().get(i).getAccountName();
          String accountDescription = response.body().get(i).getAccountDescription();
          int numberOfMembers = response.body().get(i).getNumberOfMembers();
          BigDecimal amountPaid = response.body().get(i).getTotalAmountPaid();
          BigDecimal amountOwed = response.body().get(i).getTotalAmountOwed();
          int testRes = R.drawable.human_photo;

          //Value setting works fine
          GroupAccount groupAccount = new GroupAccount(groupAccountId,
              adminId,
              accountName,
              accountDescription,
              numberOfMembers,
              amountPaid,
              amountOwed,
              testRes);

          //Values are now null here???
          groupAccounts.add(groupAccount);
        }
        setUpFAB();
        setUpNavDrawer();
        setUpAccountPreviewRecyclerView();
        emptyRVTextViewSetUp(checkIfListIsEmpty(groupAccounts));
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onFailure(Call<List<GroupAccount>> call, Throwable t) {

  }
});
```

}

My list is set like this at the start of the class:

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

List<GroupAccount> groupAccounts = new ArrayList<>();
.
...rest of class
.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not set the objects in the constructor

Your Code:

```
public GroupAccount(long groupAccountId,
                  long adminId,
                  String accountName,
                  String accountDescription,
                  int numberOfMembers,
                  BigDecimal totalAmountPaid,
                  BigDecimal totalAmountOwed,
                  int testResourceId) {

}
```

Correct Constructor:

```
public GroupAccount(long groupAccountId,
                  long adminId,
                  String accountName,
                  String accountDescription,
                  int numberOfMembers,
                  BigDecimal totalAmountPaid,
                  BigDecimal totalAmountOwed,
                  int testResourceId) {

this.groupAccountId = groupAccountId;
this.adminId = adminId;
this.accountName = accountName;
this.accountDescription = accountDescription;
this.numberOfMembers = numberOfMembers;
this.totalAmountPaid = totalAmountPaid;
this.totalAmountOwed = totalAmountOwed;
this.testResourceId = testResourceId; 
}
```

Source: [Java Contrsuctor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

Comment: Duh!! Slow day for me.. I removed one variable from my main constructor and forgot to set the values. Thanks for pointing it out!